# how to display 4 cards with different images using props in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

i can`t display my cards images in the screen it only display one image repeat

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsYWb.png)

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xc58c.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4vNE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MckEB.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp1B1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZ74i.png)

I don`t know how to make more props or how to set the right code coz i`m still learning react

Comment: On line 12 in `function Contact()` it should say `<img src={props.img}/>` (you currently use `cat1` only).

Answer (score 0):

the best solution is to send image as a `prop` `on line 12` in your `contact` component

```
<img src={prop.image} alt=""/>
```

well you can use the following steps to make your code more optimized:

**1 -** Make a variable containing all data

```
const data = [
  {
    name: "something",
    email: "someting",
    phone: "some number",
    image: require("image Path"),
  },
  {
    name: "something",
    email: "someting",
    phone: "some number",
    image: require("image Path"),
  }
]
```

**2 -** Use `.map()` to auto generate code, this will reduce the line of code.

```
  data.map((item, index) => <Contact key={index} name={item.name} email={item.email} phone={item.phone} image={item.image}/>)
```

**3 -** use image prop `on line 12` in `Contact` Component

```
<img src={prop.image} alt=""/>
```

**Edit**

This is how you have to place it.

[image]

Comment: where i make tha variables that contain all data ? in my app.js or contact.js

Comment: add it in your app.js

Comment: I have added image to the the answer defining how to place the `data`